# How to deploy only changes from sandbox to production instead of all data from package.xml file?

Tags: apex, deployment, metadata-api, ant, package.xml

I have a jenkins setup with bitbucket and using ANT migration tool how to deploy only changes into production in CI instead of deploying changes manually.

Thanks,

Comment: http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/continuous-integration-in-salesforce-using-jenkins-and-git-video-tutorial/ ?

Comment: i have checked this link before but at that time i got some issue at i the retrieve section adding the git part(<git command="add" dir="${Sandbox1.gitDirectory}">) what directory it takes

Comment: can i manually pass the git directory instead of dir="${Sandbox1.gitDirectory}"?

Comment: Yes, of course you can. The purpose of $ values is so that you can build a configuration file. If you don't care about that, you can do whatever you'd like there.